# Can't access innerHTML of a dom node

Tags: javascript, html

html:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Assignment 3</title>
  <link href="picker.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="Picker.js"></script>

  <script>
    const picker = new Picker(document);
  </script>
</head>


<body>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th id="d0">{{H1}}</th>
      <th id="d1">{{H2}}</th>
      <th id="d2">{{H3}}</th>
      <th id="d3">{{H1}}</th>
      <th id="d4">{{H2}}</th>
      <th id="d5">{{H3}}</th>
      <th id="d6">{{H3}}</th>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <button id="prev" onclick="toPrev()"> By Tag</button>
  <button id="next" onclick="toNext()">By Id</button>
</body>
```

javascript:

```
class Picker {
  /**
   * Create a date picker
   * @param {string} containerId id of a node the Picker will be a child of
   */ 

  constructor(containerId) {

    console.log(containerId.getElementsByTagName('body').innerHTML);
    }
  }
```

When I log containerId.getElementsByTagName('body'), I seem to get the correct output. But when I try to access the innerHTML, it prints out undefined.

I also tried to access containerId.getElementById('d0'), and that returned a null. Why is this happening?

edit: I also tried console.log(containerId.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML), but that didn't work either

Comment: @TannerDolby I also tried containerId.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML, but that didn't work even though it worked on a live HTMLCollection from another project

Comment: Your script is running before the DOM finishes loading btw - put your code in the `DOMContentLoaded` event-handler instead.